# Split HTML into array (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm having to receive data from function which returns `HTML`. The best solution would be to edit the code to work better but with it being live code and not being my code. I can't edit this.

So could I get some guidance to help achieve what I need:

Returned html:

```
<a href="/newsitems">News</a>
<a href="/news/roman-catapults/16465">Roman Catapults</a>
<a href="/news/year-3-roman-experience/13835">Year 3 Roman Experience</a>
<a href="/news/year-3-dewa-roman-experience/15746">Year 3 Dewa Roman Experience</a>
<a href="/news/science-week-day-1/15423">Science Week</a><a href="/news/world-book-day/15104">World Book Day</a>
<a href="/news/year-6-trip-to-the-lion-salt-works/15762">Year 6 trip to the Lion Salt Works</a><a href="/news/learning-logs/13839">Learning Logs</a>
<a href="/news/working-together/13838">Working Together</a>
<a href="/news/learning-logs/13837">Learning Logs</a>
<a href="/news/year-2-curriculum-map-for-autumn-2/13377">Year 2 Curriculum Map for Autumn 2</a>
```

I know there is methods such as

- regex
- explode
- implode

However my knowledge on this isn't the greatest and would like a little guidance to help me learn.

What i'm trying to achieve:

- Trying to break each line into an array
- Getting the text from the link and also the link
- E.g. the first line `array => (title => "News", link => "/newsitems")`

Reason:

I can't edit the function which returns this `HTML` and I want to display the HTML better than the returned data.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Use something like [PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Are you trying to break each line into a different array item? Or each html _element_? Or...?

Comment: parsing html with php *sucks*

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php ??

Comment: Please check updated question guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a PHP HTML Parser will be the most robust solution to your problem. However, if you just want a quick one-off to break your example html into an array, you could use `explode()` on new lines as so:

```
$html = '<a href="/newsitems">News</a>
<a href="/news/roman-catapults/16465">Roman Catapults</a>
<a href="/news/year-3-roman-experience/13835">Year 3 Roman Experience</a>
<a href="/news/year-3-dewa-roman-experience/15746">Year 3 Dewa Roman Experience</a>
<a href="/news/science-week-day-1/15423">Science Week</a><a href="/news/world-book-day/15104">World Book Day</a>
<a href="/news/year-6-trip-to-the-lion-salt-works/15762">Year 6 trip to the Lion Salt Works</a><a href="/news/learning-logs/13839">Learning Logs</a>
<a href="/news/working-together/13838">Working Together</a>
<a href="/news/learning-logs/13837">Learning Logs</a>';

$array = explode("\n",$html);
$array = array_map('trim',$array);
```

If you want to further parse the array items so that you split out the link and the element text, you could do something like:

```
$final = array();

foreach($array as $v){
    $v = trim($v);

    // capture things in the href attribute and within the tags
    preg_match('/href="([^"]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/',$v,$matches);
    $final[] = array(
        'originalelement' => $v,
        'url' => $matches[1],
        'text' => $matches[2]
    );
}
```

`$final` will now have what you're looking for, something like:

```
array(
  array(
    "originalelement" => "<a href="/newsitems">News</a>",
    "url" => "/newsitems",
    "text" => "News"
  ),
  array(
    "originalelement" => "<a href="/news/roman-catapults/16465">Roman Catapults</a>",
    "url" => "/news/roman-catapults/16465",
    "text" => "Roman Catapults"
  )
)
```

Keep in mind that this solution will work *with the html you have listed here*, but html is a wily beast, and if the `<a>` elements had nested elements (such as a b or span), the regex would not capture those.